# Text input is white

Tags: android, android-edittext

One of the users of my app is having an issue where the text he enters in the EditText elements of my app is white, which effectively renders it invisible against a white background. He's the only user experiencing this issue, and it's only happening to him in my app.

As an example, here's the code for one of my EditText elements:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/usernameTextBox"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

There are dozens of these in my app, and all are essentially coded the same. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe you use dark theme style which use light color for text while some code in your app modify EditText background to white. Check your style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every android distribution can overwrite default colors for widget. Therefore, if you want all of your EditText to look the same you should explicitly set their background and text color like so:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/usernameTextBox"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:singleLine="true"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the text colour being displayed correctly, strictly set the `textColor` attribute for each declared TextView like so `android:textColor="@android:color/black"`